# setAnalyticsEnabled(true) not updating messages opened percentage

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk, mobilepush

I am using mobile cloud SDK to consume push notifications in my android app.Analytics of opened notification is not updating.I have set setAnalyticsEnabled(true) in my builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do the logs say? (ref. [Logging Interface](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/trouble-shooting/loginterface.html))  Have you overridden notification handling and included the `NotificationManager.redirectForAnalytics()`? (ref. [How to Customize Notification Handling](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html#full-control-customization) and [Javadocs](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/MarketingCloudSdk/6.4/reference/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/notifications/NotificationManager.html#redirectIntentForAnalytics(android.content.Context,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20com.salesforce.marketingcloud.notifications.NotificationMessage,%20boolean)))

Comment: Yes i have overridden notification handler.redirectForAnalytics worked for me.Thanks.